# What file do I update and How to change the style of my left navigation?

Tags: css, sharepoint-2013, master-pages

I have a css script that will change the Left Navigation and I attempted to update my seattle.html and my oslo.html to allow for these changes.  I even chose a simple css to hide the left navigation and could not get this to work.  What am I doing wrong.  This works when I add it to a single page, but not the master page.

My css exists of the following and is stored as ../../Style%20Library/css/HideLeftNav.css

```
<style>
#sideNavBox { display:none; }
#contentBox { margin-left:20px; }
</style>
```

I updated both the aboved mentioned HTML files to include this style and no change in any of my pages.  In specific I changed the following:

```
<!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify) --><link href="https://xxxxx/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="https://xxxxx/_layouts/15/1033/styles/searchv15.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW -->
```

to

```
<!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify) --><link href="https://xxxxx/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="https://xxxxx/_layouts/15/1033/styles/searchv15.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../../Style%20Library/css/LeftNav.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW -->
```

and even tried this:

```
<!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify) --><link href="https://xxxxx/_layouts/15/1033/styles/searchv15.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../../Style%20Library/css/LeftNav.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample test demo.

Create css file host in Style Library(root web).

[image]

[image]

Update Master page.

[image]

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CSSRegistration Name="/Style Library/HideLeftNav.css" runat="server"/>-->
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Well this time it is attempting to work, but I get an error messages:  Refused to apply style from 'Style%2520Library/css/HideLeftNav.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.   and   sp.ui.rte.js?rev=N%2BdWLjkIJBoPkqVeWY2xLQ%3D%3D:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'addRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access StyleSheet to insertRule
    at Function.RTE.RteUtility.addStyleSheetRule